# How to configure hotkey that performs action in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, hotkeys, keyboard-shortcuts

What software/language do I need to use to configure a hotkey to perform a task or run a sub in Excel VBA?

EX: Clicking CTRL+SHIFT+T in Chrome, activates the Excel Application, and then performs a task, such as Range("A1").Select.

Best,
George

Comment: in the Macro window you can assign a `shortcut-key` to a `Sub`

Comment: I was under the impression that once the Office application is not active, the shortcut-key defined will not work. Found AutoHotKeys software, which I will try to get to take one hotkey to activate Excel and another to perform the macro I'd like it to run. If I find a way to consolidate the two actions into one, I'll post up.

Comment: Misread your question, you want to run a `Sub` when Excel is not Active.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a Windows-Wide solution across many different applications (involving Chrome and Excel as you suggested) then I'd recommend this: http://www.autohotkey.com/